# How to run module migrations programatically in FuelPHP?

Tags: phpunit, tdd, database-migration, fuelphp

For some of my tests, I need the `setUpBeforeClass` method to run migrations on any modules present, and the `tearDownAfterClass` to migrate the modules back down again. Via the command line this is easy to do:

```
oil r migrate --modules
```

...to run the module migrations, and then:

```
oil r migrate --modules --version=0
```

...to reset them. However, in the tests I need to do this programatically, and I can't figure out how to execute the above commands using FuelPHP's [Migrate](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/migrate.html) class. Both the `latest` and `version` methods seem to require you to specify a module name, but I just want to migrate any modules that are present. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need some hack to make this working.

Here is how oil does it:

https://github.com/fuel/core/blob/1.8/develop/tasks/migrate.php#L101

Alternatively you can use `Module::loaded()` to get the loaded modules.

You can then run migrations for each module.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. Do you know if there's a way of doing it via Oil - eg. `Oil\Refine::run('import', array('--modules')`? (I tried that and it doesn't seem to work, but feels like there might be a solution along those lines...)

Comment: Well, I wouldn't mess with Oil, but I am sure that import is not the task name of migration, it is migrate. I would rather skip oil and use the methods I mentioned above: get module names, and call migrate for each. Alternatively you can also call oil using `exec`.

Comment: Argh, sorry, that was a cut-and-paste error. I meant `Oil\Refine::run('migrate', array('--module'));`. "import" is a task I wrote, and I do run Oil like that in one of my tests to test the import task, so I know it can work. Can't get it to work with "migrate" though...

Comment: As @WanWizard said, you should use Migrate in your code instead of hacking oil.

Comment: I'd like to! But I don't know how to - hence the question! :) I don't think calling Oil programatically like that is really "hacking" it, though - I'm not touching anything in Oil's codebase: just calling its publicly available methods. If that works, I don't think there's anything necessarily wrong with doing that in the `setUp` method of a test - it's just the equivalent of running an oil command.

Comment: @WanWizard and I both gave you the answer: get a list of module names and run migration for each one. I gave you how to list your modules (actually two ways), WanWizard gave you the exact code, how to run a migration for one module. Mix them and you have your solution. If your oil way is not working, you could try the way the Fuel developers show you. ;)

Comment: Reacting to oil: the fact that you can call it from code, does not mean you should.

Answer (score 1):

Migrations are run by the `Migrate` class, so you can use that in your code if you want to run migrations:

```
$results = Migrate::up(null, 'mymodulename', 'module');
```

Similarly to the task you can also use down() and current().

Note that this will not load the module, so if one of your module migrations requires a class from the module, make sure to load the module first!

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, you have to name the module here, and I'd like to write this in a generic way (because I want to run the same test suite although there might be different modules present). The oil commands above seem to do this perfectly - is there a way of using Migrate to achieve the same effect? (ie. run / revert *any* module migrations present)

Comment: Please, read my answer. There is the way. Again: get a list of ALL module (general) and run migration for them.

Comment: @mark.sagikazar: `Module::loaded()` does not work in my case - it returns an empty array - because the module contains nothing other than a few instance-specific migrations that can't go in the app itself. So the module is not in fact loaded in the code.

Comment: What about looking through module paths, as in the linked oil reference? You could just recreate the steps oil does in your code.